# "I would be very happy, if I can get a chance on work on these projects"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

Just got a informal message in a group regarding CSR activities. Can you please suggest me which one will be the best sentence.

1. I would be very happy, if I can get a chance to work on these projects.
2. Happy to hear about this, looking forward to work on these projects.
3. I am happy to be part of the same.

Comment: No. 1 is out - you *have* been given a chance. No.3 is out - part of the same *what*? No. 2 - is pretty good if you lower-case the L. It's a bit terse though: "**I am** happy to hear about this, **and am** looking forward to work**ing** on these projects."